# Firestore security rules that validates in app purchases for user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

Firestore should only allow users that have purchased an upgraded in the app to write and read to the database. How would this be achieved with security rules?

Currently I'm using Cloud Functions and custom claims. Basically when the user purchases the upgrade will a Cloud Function validate the purchase with Google or Apple and then accordingly set the appropriate custom claims that are then used in the security rules.

Is there a better and simpler way of doing this or should I just stick with this setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking custom claims is about at easy as it gets with security rules. I don't think you'll find anything easier.

Comment: Yeah that was my thought as well. Just wanted to see if anyone had any input on this but you are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) you can find detailed examples about validate Custom Claims using the Admin SDK, you can [validate the Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) through different languages for example on python:

```
# Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
auth.set_custom_user_claims(uid, {'admin': True})
# The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
# next time a new one is issued.
```

Also, this document includes the [best practices recommended](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#best_practices_for_custom_claims).